# How to show source line numbers in jstack output?

Tags: java, debugging, concurrency, jvm

This is a jstack output from a running JVM

```
"FooThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f159c2ca000 nid=0x6e21 waiting on condition ..snipped
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping) 
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.myco.impl.QueueFooThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I want the line number in QueueFooThread to show up like this frame for the Catalina process

```
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1548)
```

What should I do during compilation/bootstrap time to enable this ? Thanks

Comment: In your example, you have a native method and a method with unknown source location, neither of which can ever have line numbers displayed for them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be a complete answer, but passing the `-g` (debugging) option to `javac` enables the debugger (`jdb`) to display source information, including line numbers. I'm not sure if it'll work for your case.

Comment: Hm, I thought just -g would include all debugging info (including lines and source). But whatever works...

Answer (score 1):

Compile your source with debug option.
E.g.

```
<javac target="1.5" source="1.5" classpathref="class.path" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" debug="true" encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable debugging when the code is compiled. **Note**: For libraries, they have to have debugging enabled when they are compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with debug info is the best of course.  But if it's not your source, you can always decompile with something like jad.  That doesn't help you with line numbers but if you make some educated guesses it can still be useful in a pinch.